# Stanford POSTagger, Java heap spce memory

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

I am using Python3 on Ubuntu 14.04, and am running Stanford POSTagger on a corpus of 67 raw text articles, thje redacted python script is as follows:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger

with open('the_file.txt','r') as file:
    G=file.readlines()

stan=[]

english_postagger = POSTagger('models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger', 'stanford-postagger.jar')

for line in g:
    stan.append(english_postagger.tag(tokenize_fast(line)))
```

after several iterations of which I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:109)
at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:31)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.runTagInference(TestSentence.java:322)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.testTagInference(TestSentence.java:312)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.tagSentence(TestSentence.java:135)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagSentence(MaxentTagger.java:998)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagCoreLabelsOrHasWords(MaxentTagger.java:1788)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagAndOutputSentence(MaxentTagger.java:1798)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1709)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1770)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1543)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1499)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1842)
```

I have also run the stanford postagger from command line as:

```
java -mx300m -classpath stanford-postagger.jar   edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger -textFile sample-input.txt > sample-tagged.txt
```

with a similar error. I even passed Java 2 GB of memory, and still no luck.

Any thoughts/ideas or hacky type solutions are greatly welcomed!

Well spotted @nsanglar, so I tried:

```
java -Xmx2g -classpath stanford-postagger.jar   edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger -textFile raw_text.txt > sample-tagged.txt
```

I get an error log message, with the following header:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 283639808 bytes for committing   reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#     Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2798), pid=25677, tid=140571167794944

# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.2
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try  "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Comment: I never saw such error log, but it seems that you are trying to allocate too much memory to your application (e.g. 2Go). Can you try with less? Try -Xmx512m or -Xmx1024m and it might be better.

Comment: thanks for your help, I did as you suggested and again got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was a RAM issue, I simply did not have enough memory to execute the command. Running the tagger off a server did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you should use -Xmx1024m. I think you made a typo because currently your are using -mx :)

Comment: thanks for noting that, unfortunatley though it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In python set:

```
nltk.internals.config_java(options='-Xmx3024m')
```

Comment: Thanks, this line worked for me (with the lexParser instead of tagger)